# Compute the conditional probability that it is in fact a dog picture

Tags: probability, statistics

> The computer program CAD takes as input a randomly selected cat or dog picture from the internet and outputs the decision 'cat' or 'dog'. It is known that CAD correctly classified a cat picture with probability $0.6$ while a dog picture is correctly classified with probability $0.7$. The probability that a random picture is a cat picture equals $0.75$. Given that CAD classifies a picture as a cat, compute the conditional probability that it is in fact a dog picture.

I'm quite sure that this exercise is solvable with Bayer's Rule but I'm not able to compute it, because I think the way that I call the probabilities is not fully correct: 
$P(T|C)=0.6$ probability that classified in a true way given that is a cat 
 
$P(T|D)=0.7$ probability that classified in a true way given that is a dog 
$P(C)=0.75$ probability that is a cat
$P(T^c|C)=?$ probability that classified in a wrong way given that is a cat
$$P(T^c|C)=\frac{P(C|T^c)*P(T^c)}{P(C|T^c)*P(T^c)+P(C|T)*P(T)}$$
Where is my mistake? How can I solve it?

**Edit:**
$$P(Clas. Wrong|Clas. Cat)=\frac{P(Clas. Cat|Clas. Wrong)*P(Clas. Wrong)}{P(Clas. Cat|Clas. Wrong)*P(Clas. Wrong)+P(Clas. Cat|Clas. Correct)*P(Clas. Correct)}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake seems to be in thinking that the problem asks for (in your notation), $P(T^c|C)$, i.e., the probability that the classification is wrong (event $T^c$) given that the picture is actually a cat (event $C$).  The question actually asks for the probability that the classification is wrong given that the picture is **classified as** a cat.  In other words, you were computing the probability of a cat picture being classified as a dog, whereas the problem is about the reverse eerror.

Once you correct that issue, Bayes's theorem should do the job for you. When I did the calculation, I got a probability of $1/7$ (which you're apparently supposed to round off to $0.14$).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I edited the question, but now I have problems to visualize the probabilities with this notation, can you help me?

Comment: The probability that a picture is really a dog but is classified as a cat is $0.25\times0.3=0.075$. The probability that a picture is really a cat and is classified as a cat is $0.75\times0.6=0.45$. So the total probability of being classified as a cat is $0.075+0.45=0.525$. So the conditional probability of being really a dog, given that it's classified as a cat, is $0.075/0.525$, which reduces to $1/7$.

Comment: Now I understand where I was wrong in the notation, thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Applying Bayes' Theorem

P( Picuture is CAT/Classified as CAT) $= 0.6\times 0.75 = 0.45\tag1$

P( Picture is DOG/Classfied as CAT)$=0.3\times 0.25 = 0.075\tag2$

What is asked is P(Classified as CAT/Picture is Dog) $= \frac{(2)}{(1)+(2)}$

Comment: Thank you  but I can't find the correct answer with this formula

Comment: Could you tell me what the answer is?

Comment: is one of these $0.14$, $0.38$, $0.08$, $0.25$, $0.4$, $0.3$ and with your method I have $0.105$